# how to access unknown parameters passed using ... to a function in c

Tags: c, function, variadic-functions

Sometimes when we don't know how many and which parameters need to be passed to a function, then we pass it using three periods (ellipsis) ... but how to access these parameters inside the function?

Comment: There are many tutorials and examples of using *variable argument functions* (a.k.a. *varags* functions). Just search for it.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8.aspx

Comment: Thanks for those links those really helped.

Comment: Also note that using variadic functions is bad practice, since they have horrible type safety.